# How to transcoding emoji in iOS ？

Tags: ios, emoji

I'm studying Objective-C.When my project need transcoding emoji ,I don't know how to deal with it.

The Requirement are follow:

1.when user send their comment , I should transcoding emoji to a string like unicode or utf-8 cause our server don't store emoji.

2.when user load comment data ,I should transcoding string to a emoji which was System comes (now is iOS 10 which have National flag cost 4 btyes) .And present emoji in device.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How efficient do you need? You could convert the emoji its unicode hex ID, store that pretty much anywhere (if you can't encode 0-9,A-F you have bigger problems) and simply do the opposite client side.

Comment: now I split comment into character which judge it whether is a emoji.If yes,I transcoding it into a string like this [emoji:D83DDE00]  (I use utf-16 and relpace "\\U"  with " " and add prefix [emoji: and ] )                                                   and now the question become when I get such string how did I transcoding to a emoji and present in devide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before saving the comment to server use the below code

```
NSData *dataForEmoji = [comment dataUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *encodevalue = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:dataForEmoji encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Save the encodedvalue to your server.

When you retrieve use below code before you display

```
NSString *emojiText = [NSString stringWithCString:[textFromServer cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                  encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Comment: This is my first use stackoverflow. And I want follow you to know more knowledge about iOS.But I don't know how to follow you .

Comment: You are welcome. Even I am new to stackoverflow. I don see such option here. You can post if any doubts you have here. There are many people here with more knowledge to help you. Even I will try to help you if required. anyways You can find me in skype/fb using my id ravikiran.b2003